# Not able to return the value while using async function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, async-await, return-value

Trying to return the value after google api call in the below async function in google cloud function

```
 async function getGoogleApiToken() {
      let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
               privatekey.client_email,
               null,
               privatekey.private_key,
               ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute']);
        //authenticate request
       await jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
         if (err) {
           console.log(err);
           return;
         } else {
           console.log("Successfully connected!"+ tokens.access_token); //displaying the token correctly
           return tokens.access_token; //returns the token
         }
        });
    }
  exports.consumepromise = async (req,res) =>{
  const tokennew =  await getGoogleApiToken();
  console.log("token"+tokennew);
  }
```

Error: tokennew is undefined

Not sure where it is going wrong.

Comment: You are `await`ing `jwtClient.authorize` but not doing anything with the return value. Your return statement is inside the scope of the callback function you passed to `jwtClient.authorize`, not the scope of your function `getGoogleApiToken`, which returns nothing.

Comment: so how do i modify the code to work?

Comment: ` google.auth.JWT` is from which npm package ?? @Jax

Comment: googleapis package. which is working fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I had to guess it's because `jwtClient.authorize` accepts a callback instead of returning a promise -

```js
async function getGoogleApiToken() {
  let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(...);
  await jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    } else {
      console.log("Successfully connected!"+ tokens.access_token); //displaying the token correctly
      return tokens.access_token; //returns the token // <- NO IT DOESN'T
    }
  });
}
```

Callbacks cannot `return` a value. This is one of the [most popular questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) on StackOverflow. Callbacks like the ones used in `jwtClient.authorize` are just a common usage pattern and do not interop with `async` and `await` directly. You must return a `Promise` from your `getGoogleApiToken`. One such way is to wrap a Promise around the `jwtClient.authorize` call -

```js
async function getGoogleApiToken() {
  const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(...); // <-- btw use const
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => // <-- wrap in promise
    jwtClient.authorize((err, tokens) => {
      if (err)
        reject(err) // <-- reject the error
      else
        resolve(tokens) // <-- resolve the result
    })
  )
}
```

We don't want to add this Promise wrapper every time we wish to use a callback-accepting function with other Promise-based code, including any `async` functions. Turning any callback-accepting async function into a promise-returning async function can be a mechanical process. In fact, that's what NodeJS's [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) does. It works something like this -

```js
// approximation of util.promisify
const promisify = f => (...args) =>
  new Promise ((pass, fail) =>
    f (...args, (err, result) => err ? fail(err) : pass(result))
  )

// example callback-accepting function
const demoCallbackFunc = (a, b, callback) =>
  setTimeout(callback, 1000, null, a + b)

// ordinary call
demoCallbackFunc(3, 5, (err, res) => {
  if (err)
    console.error(err)
  else
    console.log(res)
})

// promisified
promisify(demoCallbackFunc)(3, 5)
  .then(console.log, console.error)

console.log("please wait 1 second...")
```

Using `promisify` in your program will clean it up considerably -

```js
async function getGoogleApiToken() {
  const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(...);
  const auth = promisify(jwtClient.authorize.bind(jwtClient))
  return auth() // <-- no need for await, auth already returns a promise
}
```

Or without an intermediate assignment of `auth` -

```js
async function getGoogleApiToken() {
  const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(...);
  return promisify(jwtClient.authorize.bind(jwtClient))()
}
```

Or without `bind` using an arrow function -

```js
async function getGoogleApiToken() {
  const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(...);
  return promisify(callback => jwtClient.authorize(callback))()
}
```

Comment: you made my day :)

Comment: @Jax Happy to help. See the link I added in paragraph 2 for more insight. All the best :D

Comment: @Thankyou In this statement that you have mentioned const auth = promisify(jwtClient.authorize.bind(jwtAuthorize)), what is jwtAuthorize variable here?

Comment: My apologies for the typo, Jax. It is supposed to be `jwtClient.authorize.bind(jwtClient)`. I fixed it in the post too :)

Answer (score 0):

`const tokennew =  await getGoogleApiToken();` should be inside an async block or you can use .then and .catch on it like so:

with async block

```
  async function consumePromise() {
   const tokennew =  await getGoogleApiToken();
   console.log("token"+tokennew);
  }
  // then call it
  consumePromise();
```

with then and catch

```
   getGoogleApiToken()
     .then(tokennew => {
       console.log("token"+tokennew);
     })
     .catch(err => {
       console.log(err);
     })
```

The most important thing to note here is that you can't access a value resolved by a promise outside an async block or without using .then and .catch on the promise.

Comment: i have already implemeted didnt added in query, now added the full code